# Getting the first letter in the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I'm trying to get only the names that begin with "L" or "l" to be echoed out.

```
$array = array('Leanna', 'nicole', 'Lisa', 'Sarah', 'Leopard', 'Michael', 'jack', 'logan');

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $exp_key = explode('L', $key);
    if($exp_key[0] == 'L' || $exp_key[0] == "l"){
        $arr_result[] = $value;
    }

    echo $value . "<br />";
}
```

but I still get all the values

Comment: You're exploding the *key*…?!

Comment: The test the first letter, all you need is `$value[0] == 'L'`.

Comment: `explode('L', $key)` will not do your job. You should have a look at what explode is designed for https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Answer (score 2):

#### What's wrong with your code?

This is the code you posted in the question:

```
$array = array('Leanna', 'nicole', 'Lisa', 'Sarah', 'Leopard', 'Michael', 'jack', 'logan');

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $exp_key = explode('L', $key);
    if($exp_key[0] == 'L' || $exp_key[0] == "l"){
        $arr_result[] = $value;
    }

    echo $value . "<br />";
}
```

**How it works?**

On the first iteration, `$key` is set to number `0` and `$value` is the string `'Leanna'`.

The statement `$exp_key = explode('L', $key);` converts `$key` to the string `'0'` and splits it into an array of strings using the string `'L'` as separator. Since there is no `L` inside `0`, the result is an array that contains only one element: the input string (`array(0 => '0')`). Consequently, `$exp_key[0]` is the string `'0'`.

According to the [table of loose comparisons using `==`](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), the string `'0'` is not equal to neither `'L'` nor `'l'` and the statement inside the `if` block doesn't execute.

The `echo $value` statement, however, is executed and it prints `Leanna<br />`.

On the next loop, `$key` is the number `1` and `$value` is the string `'nicole'`. The processing works similar to the first iteration, the comparisons produce the same result (`false`), nothing is stored in `$arr_result` and `$value` is printed. The same happens again and again until all the elements of `$array` are processed.

### How to make it work

First, you shouldn't care about the keys of `$array`. They are consecutive integer numbers starting with `0` and they are not useful in any way for the goal.

Then, you should compare `$value[0]` against uppercase and lowercase `L`. There is no need to [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) anything, all you care about is [the first character of each value](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr).

The code could look like this:

```
$array = array('Leanna', 'nicole', 'Lisa', 'Sarah', 'Leopard', 'Michael', 'jack', 'logan');

// Make sure $arr_result is always an array
// Cannot rely on the assignment inside the loop to initialize it because 
// if no value in $array starts with 'L', the statement $arr_result[] = $value
// is never executed and at the end $arr_result is undefined.
$arr_result = array();

foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($value[0] == 'L' || $value[0] == 'l'){
        $arr_result[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($arr_result);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Leanna
    [1] => Lisa
    [2] => Leopard
    [3] => logan
)
```

### Alternative solutions

You can use the PHP function [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to extract from `$array` only the matching values:

```
$arr_result = array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($value) {
        return strtoupper($value[0]) == 'L';
    }
);
```

This solution is slightly slower than manually looping through the array but it is more clear. The [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) used as [callback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) does only the comparison (the filtering) and the assignment to `$arr_result` happens only once, when `array_filter()` returns. There is no need to initialize `$arr_result` any more because `array_filter()` always returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$value` and don't need to `explode()`. And you were echoing `$value` which will give you all values, you rather need to use `$arr_result` variable:

```
<?php
$array = array('Leanna', 'nicole', 'Lisa', 'Sarah', 'Leopard', 'Michael', 'jack', 'logan');

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if($value[0] == 'L' || $value[0] == "l"){
        $arr_result[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($arr_result);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Leanna
    [1] => Lisa
    [2] => Leopard
    [3] => logan
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the buildt in function [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

> array_map — Applies the callback to the elements of the given Arrays

```
$array = array('Leanna', 'nicole', 'Lisa', 'Sarah', 'Leopard', 'Michael', 'jack', 'logan');


array_map("getEntries", $array);

function getEntries($e) {
    if($e[0] == "L" || $e[0] == "l") {
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

explode('l',$arr) removes l from the resulting array

```
$arr_result=[];
$array = array('Leanna', 'nicole', 'Lisa', 'Sarah', 'Leopard', 'Michael', 'jack', 'logan');
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if($value[0] == 'L' || $value[0] == "l"){
        $arr_result[] = $value;
    }

    echo $value . "<br />";
}

print_r($arr_result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array('Leanna', 'nicole', 'Lisa', 'Sarah', 'Leopard', 'Michael', 'jack', 'logan');

foreach($array as $value){
    $lettersArray = explode('', $value);
    if($lettersArray[0] == 'L' || $lettersArray[0] == "l"){
        $arr_result[] = $value;
        // echo $value . "<br />";  # to echo names as you go
    }
}

print_r ($result) // if you want to print all the values as an array at the end
```

Try this. But i think there should be a more simple way as well :D

The thing wrong with your code is that you echo every value in every iteration in the cycle and only add it to array if it is correct.